# Why cant we just have a "sign out on this computer" button?

Tags: google-chrome

Does it make sense for chrome to make a simple button that signs you out of the computer you are working on.
The button name could be "log me out on this computer only".
I have read many of the posts offering work around's regarding the issue. 
It seems odd that signing in or out is this complicated.
This should be a no brainer, why all the work around's to do such a simple thing?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `chrome://settings/`

Select the button titled `Disconnect your Google Account...`

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something similar to this:
(http://www.labnol.org/software/create-family-profiles-in-google-chrome/4394/)

It allows the creation of profiles in chrome so you can switch between users. If you are doing this for a security concern you can do what @Kruug suggests.